# Como se chama a inserção de um som vogal extra entre duas consoantes, típica dalguns falantes brasileiros?

Tags: português-brasileiro, fonologia

Enquanto os portugueses tendem a elidir na fala algumas vogais não acentuadas, alguns brasileiros vão ao extremo oposto e inserem em certas palavras um som /i/ extra para separar duas consoantes adjacentes na escrita. Por exemplo, como podem ouvir se seguirem os links abaixo:

> [*ritmo* é pronunciado como *rítimo*](http://pt.forvo.com/word/ritmo/#pt) (enquanto um outro brasileiro e uma portuguesa dizem *ritmo*)
>
> [*encriptado* é pronunciado como *encripitado*](http://pt.forvo.com/word/encriptado/#pt)
>
> e a mesma senhora pronuncia [*hipnótico* como *hipinótico*](http://pt.forvo.com/word/hipn%C3%B3tico/#pt)
>
> [*obtém* é pronunciado como *obitém*](http://pt.forvo.com/word/obt%C3%AAm/#pt) (mas outro brasileiro pronuncia como *obtém*)

Os links acima mostram a localização dos falantes, e creio os falantes que inserem o /i/ extra são do Rio de Janeiro ou perto. E eu lembro-me que um meu amigo gaúcho comentava isso acerca dum amigo carioca. Isto é um fenómeno regional?

Existe um nome técnico para este fenómeno e para o som vogal extra?

Comment: Não creio tratar-se de um fenômeno regional. Talvez seja mais relacionado ao nível educacional.  Mas não posso afirmar.

Comment: Não, é regionalismo mesmo.  Eu tenho pós-doutorado e faço exatamente isso.  =D

Comment: @MarceloVentura Pois, esse meu amigo carioca também tem doutorado. Então é regionalismo de que regiões? Precisamos de uma resposta com um mapa das vogais epentéticas no Brasil :)

Comment: Suspeito que essa vogal epentética seja de uso corrente no Brasil como um todo, viu.  Infelizmente, não sei dar uma referência de cabeça.  Teria que procurar primeiro.  Além do mais, isso já não seria uma nova pergunta?

Comment: @MarceloVentura  Como disseste no primeiro comentário que era regionalismo, pensei que soubesse de regiões onde acontece e doutras onde não acontece. Tens razão, o foco da pergunta está no nome do fenómeno e não na distribuição geográfica.

Comment: Valeu Marcelo. Sou de Mossoró-rn e você reforçou minha vontade de terminar minha graduação em letras.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O fenómeno geral de acrescentar sons a palavras chama-se [*epêntese*](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/ep%C3%AAntese). Este termo é normalmente usado para os sons intercalados dentro de palavras (em vez de no início ou no fim). Então os /i/ intercalados entre consoantes são *vogais epentéticas*.

Há também um termo mas específico para a epêntese duma vogal, [*anaptixe*](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/anaptixe), com o adjectivo correspondente [*anaptíctico*](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/anapt%C3%ADctico). Parece-me menos usado do que epêntese. Um sinónimo é [suarabácti](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/suarab%C3%A1cti).

O Wikipédia em inglês tem [um bom artigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis) sobre isso, e [menciona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis#In_informal_speech) em particular o caso dos /i/ epentéticos no Brasil. Infelizmente, neste momento [o correspondente no português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ep%C3%AAntese) não passa de um esboço.

Comment: Pouco usado?! Vou passar a usar todos os dias :) [É *anaptíctico* no Brasil e *anaptítico* em Portugal](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=32843).