# Pronúncia da palavra "subsídio"

Tags: pronúncia

É comum - e muito mais frequente, ao menos no Brasil - escutarmos a palavra "`subsídio`" falada como "`sub \z\ ídio`", ou seja, com o segundo "`S`" tendo som de "`Z`".

No entanto, costumo escutar que um "`S`" após o prefixo "`SUB`" teria som de "`S`", tal como ocorre em "`subsistema`" ou "`subsolo`". Não sei se é esta a explicação, mas gostaria de saber se realmente esse "`S`" deve ser pronunciado com som de "`S`" na norma culta e se a explicação é realmente esta. Costumo falar com som de "`S`", mas confesso que tenho esta dúvida.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pelos vistos a pronúncia de *subsídio* tem dado que falar no Brasil: já deu artigo na [Veja](http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/consultorio/a-pronuncia-de-%E2%80%98subsidio%E2%80%99-erro-hoje-regra-amanha/), na [Sua Língua do Prof. Cláudio Moreno](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/18/transar-obsequio-e-subsidio/) e na [Gramaticalhas](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI8503,41046-Subsidio).

A pronúncia tradicional, e portanto considerada mais correta, é com o som /s/ (de ***s***apo) e não /z/ (de ***z***ona). Esta é aliás a pronúncia do ***s*** após letra consoante, exceto em palavras como *transição, transigência, transação, transalpino*, etc., e também em *obséquio* e derivados; nestas palavras o ***s*** é pronunciado /z/.

Agora, os artigos da Veja e Sua Lingua confirmam que muitos brasileiros, 95% na impressão pessoal do Prof. Moreno, pronunciam a palavra como *subzídio*. O Prof. Moreno diz que o mesmo tende a acontecer com *subsistência* e *subsistir*. (Não creio que isto aconteça com estas palavras em Portugal, mas pergunto-me se não acontecerá com *observar, observação*.)

Os artigos da Veja e Sua Língua observam contudo que desvios generalizados à pronúncia considerada correta numa época tendem a tornar-se na pronúncia oficial em época posterior. O Prof. Moreno sugere que esta tendência de alterar a pronúncia de certos ***s*** para /z/ «revela a atuação de alguma força concreta e irresistível».

A pronúncia é governada em parte pela lei do menor esforço. Eu pergunto-me se quem pronuncia subsídio como *subzídio* não tenderá, ao falar, a fazer a separação silábica entre *su* e *bsí*, em vez de entre *sub* e *sí*. É muito fácil pronunciar /bz/ (os dois sons são sonoros, isto é, são produzidos com vibração na garganta) e /ps/ (os dois sons são surdos, sem vibração na garganta), mas /bs/ e /pz/ são difíceis de pronunciar de seguida. Para quem faça a separação silábca entre *sub* e *si*, a dificuldade não existe. É claro que também não existe para quem separa o *sub* do *sí* com um ***i*** epentético (*sub**i**ssídio*), como é muito comum no Brasil, e nesse caso a dificuldade também não existe.

Comment: Na minha experiência, palavras como subsídio se pronunciam no Brasil como se fossem: sub-i-sidio. Eu pessoalmente nunca ouvi ninguém trocar o fonema /s/ por /z/ como se fosse: subzídio. Da mesma forma, se ouve: ob-i-servação. Esta introdução do som i como intervocálica não se ouve em Portugal, certo? E até se o Prof. Moreno tivesse razão, ele esqueceu o i, porque ainda assim ficaria: sub-i-zidio. Isso tudo tem a sua lógica....

Comment: _transigência_, etc. não estão na mesma categoria de _obséquio_. No primeiro caso, o _s_ continua entre duas vogais; o facto de /ɐ̃/ se escrever  aqui _an_ é apenas um artefacto da ortografia atual.

Comment: Um vídeo explicativo: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AhhMQgVwP_I)

Comment: @Lambie Pronunciar o segundo ***s*** de subsídio como /z/ parece ser comum no Brasil. O artigo da Veja diz o mesmo,e há muita coisa na net sobre isso. Sim, nós em Portugal só elidimos vogais (diferente > difrente), não as acrescentamos. Essas vogais epentéticas já foram abordadas [nesta pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3019/como-se-chama-a-inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-som-vogal-extra-entre-duas-consoantes-t%C3%ADpica-dal). Eu não apresento a transcrição fonética de *subsídio*, limito-me a alterar a grafia para se perceber o quero dizer.

Comment: @Artefacto Nem me tinha dado conta disso. Mas estava em todo o caso a pensar em letras consoantes.

Comment: O comentário de @Lambie sobre a introdução do i indica a mim, criado e educado no sul do Brasil, português pobre e incorreto. Também considero assim a pronúncia de s com som de x (mesmo > mexmo), como acontece no Rio de Janeiro, cuja desculpa é "sotaque".